# Nginx + php7.1-fpm, upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Nginx and php7.1-fpm on Ubuntu 16.04. It was working perfectly fine. I am started getting `504 Gateway Time-out` error.

When I checked the Nginx log, I got this errors:

```
 *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: server.name,, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
```

Here is my virtual host file

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        location / {

                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


    location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Please guide why I am getting this error. How can I resolve it.

Comment: Did you find out what your issue was?

Comment: Maybe you have an error in your php code. We resolve similar issue fixing our code like next answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070299/nginx-php-fpm-504-timeout-error-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-o